# How to re-render component in Angular after subscribe

Tags: angular

I have the following code in the parent component

In parent.component.ts

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, private elementRef:ElementRef, private apiService: ApiService) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
    // Some Code
    
    this.apiService.getFilters(this.metric).subscribe((results: FilterItem[][]) => {
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
        this.regionList = results[0];
        this.subregionList=results[1];
    })
    
    // Some Code
}
```

In parent.component.html

```
<app-filter-unit [checkBoxListActual]="regionList" [selectedCheckboxList]="selectedRegionList" (listUpdated)="updateRegions($event)">
</app-filter-unit>
```

In child component filter-unit.component.ts

```
checkBoxList: any[] = [];
@Input() selectedCheckboxList = ['ALL'];
@Output() listUpdated = new EventEmitter();
@Input()  checkBoxListActual: any[] = [];
searchword: any="";

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.checkBoxListActual = [...new Set(this.checkBoxListActual)];

    if(this.selectedCheckboxList && this.selectedCheckboxList.length > 0) {
      if(this.selectedCheckboxList[0] == 'ALL') {
        this.selectedCheckboxList.pop();
      }
    }
    if(this.selectedCheckboxList.length == 0 ) {
      this.selectedCheckboxList = [...this.checkBoxListActual];
    }
    this.checkBoxList = [...this.checkBoxListActual];

    this.checkBoxList = [...new Set(this.checkBoxList)];
    this.selectedCheckboxList = [...new Set(this.selectedCheckboxList)];
}
```

In filter-unit.component.html

```
<div style="overflow: auto;height: 140px;">
    <div *ngFor="let content of checkBoxList; let i=index" >
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="unit-checkbox" 
            [checked]="selectedCheckboxList.indexOf(content) >= 0" value="content"
            (change)="onClickCheckbox1(content, $event)">
        </span>
        <span>&nbsp;{{content}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the program runs, app-filter-unit will have "regionList" to be empty, as this is the initial value.
But I have asynchronous api call getFilters which will set the regionList.
And I want Angular to redraw app-filter-unit, as now "regionList" will have some value.

How to do this?

Comment: the child component should be updated by default. If not, it means there is a custom way to detect changes into your app

Comment: @GérômeGrignon what do you mean of custom way? And where is it located? is it in the parent component or child component?

Comment: Angular is doing change detection operations by default, by using `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef`, it means you are overriding these operations for custom ones. About your project, it's hard to tell without further code samples.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon I've added some codes on the child component part... Is it enough? Now, the `checkBoxList` is initialized on ngOnInit(), and this is called once, before the subscribe finishes. so when the child component tries to loop it, it is empty.

Comment: here is an simple example (i added a 2s delay to simulate your situation) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g9gw6z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I did not see the 2s delay. Have you updated the code?

Comment: oh i'm sorry, i forgot to save it : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g9gw6z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `@Input() selectedCheckboxList` should be updated automatically if you use default change detection. But the template actually binds to `checkBoxList`, which you only initialize in `ngOnInit()`.
The changes happening after your `FilterUnitComponent` has been initialized never appear in `checkBoxList` and hence are not rendered.

If you want to react to changes to your inputs, you can implement [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) by implementing `ngOnChanges()`. According to the [lifecycle hooks docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks):

> Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

---

Alternatively, you could also define setters for the Inputs you want to react to. The setter will be called every time your Input changes.

```
private _selectedCheckBoxList: any[];

get selectedCheckBoxList(): any[] {
    return this._selectedCheckBoxList;
}
@Input() set selectedCheckBoxList(value: any[]) {
    this._selectedCheckBoxList = value;
    // TODO: update this.checkBoxList
}
```